# Not able to delete Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created one database from ssms 2017 version on azure sql server with .bacpac file, but when I am trying to access it from azure portal it is not showing under azure sql server instance. But when I am login into that instance with SSMS it is showing that database. Need help on this, can anyone face this problem.

regards 
Sandy

Comment: How did you do that with SSMS? Can show us your steps?

Comment: did you refresh your azure portal?

Comment: I login to my SSMS with azure sql server credential. Then right click on datbases and click on Import data-tier application option. After that I selected my bacpac file and entered datbase name, after that finish the data import. After import finish it created successfully in SSMS but when i checked into my azure portal account it is not showing that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From azure portal I raise ticket regarding this issue, they solved my problem. Added my Azure Sql database to my subscription. During .bacpac file restore some issue occur due to which it wasn't show on portal. Also I am able to delete that datbase from SSMS generated delete script for database.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same operation successfully. I imported a new database with a BACPAC file to my Azure SQL Database. Please reference my steps:

1. connect to my Azure SQL Database instance with SSMS, right-click `Databsse`, choose `Import Data-tire Application`. I import the DB2 database from my BACPAC files.

[image]

2. `Import Settings`.
   [image]
3. Complete the import. After the import job finished, we can see the database DB2.
   [image]
4. Check the database on Azure Portal. Login my portal, choose the SQL server which our database instance host on in home page.
   [image]
   Click in the SQL server and we can find the new database DB2.
   [image]

My SSMS version is the latest v17.9.1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup I did the same, but my problem is it is not listing that database on azure portal.